# SSHFS user name containing colon syntax

Tags: sshfs

I can connect to my server using ssh :

```
ssh -p 22 root@app_name:userName@host
```

But sshfs thinks app_name is my host :

```
sshfs -odebug,sshfs_debug,loglevel=debug -o allow_other -p 22 root@app_name:userName@host:/path/toRemote/ /path/to/local
```

How can i manage to make it work ?

I have tried escaping the colon and the arobase with \

I have also tried using quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited my .ssh/config like this :

```
Host server1
 HostName host
 Port 22
 User userName
```

And then I can call it like that :

```
sshfs server1:/data /path/ToLocalMountPoint
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).